# Scala for comprehension vs. foreach

Tags: scala

In the Scala shell I did this:

```
import java.util._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val t: SortedMap[String,Int] = new TreeMap[String,Int] () // produces an empty java.util.SortedMap

t("a") = 1; t("b") = 2; t("A") = 3; t("0") = 4

t // prints: res35: java.util.SortedMap[String,Int] = {0=4, A=3, a=1, b=2}, as expected

t foreach println // also prints the (k,v) pairs in the same TreeMap sorted order
```

However, the following statement does not print the pairs in sorted order, it appears to print them in hash bucket order, (0,4) (b,2) (A,3) (a,1):

```
for ((k,v) <- t) printf("(%s,%d)%n", k, v)
```

In other answers related to for and foreach it seems that a for comprehension is supposed to translate into a use of foreach like so:

> "A for-comprehension for (p <- e) e0 is translated to e.foreach { case p => e0 }"

but that does not seem to be what is happening here.

Note that if I create a *scala* SortedMap from a *scala* TreeMap that both the foreach and the for produce the (k,v) pairs in sorted order as I expected.  It seems like some way that the Java TreeMap is being converted for scala is different.

Any comments or ideas about why this discrepancy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `p` and `(k,v)` are not the same thing. Your for-comprehension is translated thus:

```
t.filter{
  case (k, v) => true
  case _      => false
}.map {
  case (k, v) => printf("(%s,%d)$n")
}
```

Once `filter` puts it's hands on the java collection, it becomes a Scala collection, and is no longer sorted.

As a side note, on Scala 2.10 the above is no longer true since it detects that there's no element that isn't a (k,v) from the static type at compile time, and doesn't generate the filter. Here:

```
scala> for ((k,v) <- t) printf("(%s,%d)%n", k, v)
<console>:15: warning: dead code following this construct
              for ((k,v) <- t) printf("(%s,%d)%n", k, v)
                         ^
(0,4)
(A,3)
(a,1)
(b,2)

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> reify{for ((k,v) <- t) printf("(%s,%d)%n", k, v)}
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] =
Expr[Unit](scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(t).foreach(((x$1) => x$1: @unchecked match {
  case scala.Tuple2((k @ _), (v @ _)) => scala.this.Predef.printf("(%s,%d)%n", k, v)
})))
```

PS: Prefer `JavaConverters` over `JavaConversions`.

Comment: @BobYacobellis I just made it better. :-)

Comment: I see that the statement I actually wanted was this:  `for (kv <- t) printf("(%s,%d)%n", kv._1, kv._2)`

Comment: a better statement is `for (kv <- t) println(kv)`.